# XML Serialisation to file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I would like to achieve the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StatisticsFunctionsSetting xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <StatisticsFunctions>
    <Visibility>false</Visibility>
  </StatisticsFunctions>
</StatisticsFunctionsSetting>
```

using the following bool property

```
[XmlArray("StatisticsFunctions")]
[XmlArrayItem("Visibility")]
public bool IsShowChecked
{
    get
    {
        return this.isShowChecked;
    }

    set
    {
        this.isShowChecked = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("IsShowChecked");
    }
}
```

It is crashing on `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`. Does the property have to be an array and not bool? I would like to keep the boolean property, so please advice the XML attribute to use.

Comment: What error do you receive at the crash?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll. Error reflecting type

Comment: when executing this code :

Comment: {
                setting =
                    new XmlSerializer(typeof(StatisticsFunctionsSetting)).Deserialize(stream) as
                    StatisticsFunctionsSetting;

Comment: You need to declare an array property and then add [XmlArray] to that if needbe. You are trying to use a scalar property as an array.

Comment: Thanks. as you can see, I am just trying to save the visibility property using boolean. Does it mean an array will have to be used ?

Comment: No you can just get rid of the attributes and let it serialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"C:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StatisticsFunctionsSetting settings = new StatisticsFunctionsSetting(){
                statisticsFunctions = new List<StatisticsFunctions>(){
                    new StatisticsFunctions(){
                        visibility = new List<bool>(){true,true, false}
                    }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StatisticsFunctionsSetting));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializerNamespaces _ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            _ns.Add("", "");
            serializer.Serialize(writer, settings, _ns);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StatisticsFunctionsSetting));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            StatisticsFunctionsSetting  newSettings = (StatisticsFunctionsSetting)xs.Deserialize(reader);


        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("StatisticsFunctionsSetting")]
    public class StatisticsFunctionsSetting
    {
        [XmlElement("StatisticsFunctions")]
        public List<StatisticsFunctions> statisticsFunctions {get;set;}
    }
    [XmlRoot("StatisticsFunctions")]
    public class StatisticsFunctions
    {
        [XmlElement("Visibility")]
        public List<Boolean> visibility { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes.  If you  don't then you get another level of tags which you don't want.  You can comment out the two XMLElement lines and then compare the the XML file and see the differences.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN: You can apply the XmlArrayAttribute to a public field or read/write property that returns an array of objects. You can also apply it to collections and fields that return an ArrayList or any field that returns an object that implements the IEnumerable interface.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Use an array of bool or manual serialize/deserialize.